# Find a string pattern using Regular expression

Tags: c#, .net

How can I use regular expressions to find if the string matches a pattern like `[sometextornumber] is a [sometextornumber].`
For instance, if the input is `This is a test`, the output should be `this` and `test`.

I was thinking something like `([a-zA-Z0-9]) is a([a-zA-Z0-9])` but looks like I am way off the correct path.

Comment: Please get regex cheat sheet and carefully deconstruct your regular expression to know why it does not work you'd need to do it anyway as obviously someone will post solutions without  any explanation soon.

Comment: "(.*) is a (.*)" will capture 2 groups before and after " is a ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is geared towards grabbing the first and last word of a sentence.  If this is all you're going to be interested in, this pattern will suffice:

```
"^(\\w+)|(\\w+)$"
```

Pattern breakdown:

```
^ indicates the beginning of a line    
^(\\w+) capture group for a word at the beginning of the line. This is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9]+, where the + says you want a one or more letters and numbers.
| acts as an OR operator in Regex
$ indicates the end of a line
(\\w+)$ capture group for a word at the end of the line. This is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9]+, where the + says you want a one or more letters and numbers.
```

This pattern allows you to ignore what's in between the first and last word, so it doesn't care about "is a", and give you one capture group to pull from.

Usage:

```
string data = "This is going to be a test";
Match m = Regex.Match(data, "^(\\w+)|(\\w+)$");
while (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0]);
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Results:

```
This
test
```

If you're really only interested in the first and last word of a sentence, you also don't need to bother with Regex.  Just split the sentence by a space and grab the first and last element of the array.

```
string[] dataPieces = data.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(dataPieces[0]);
Console.WriteLine(dataPieces[dataPieces.Length - 1]);
```

And the results are the same.

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])+ is a ([a-zA-Z0-9])+
```

Edit:

You need a space after the `a` since it is another word. Without the `+` it will only match from last letter of the first word till the first letter of the last word. The `+` will match 1 or more of whatever is in the `()`, so in this case the whole word.

Comment: This is good example of "solution without any explanation"... As a bonus it produces useless capture groups. Fixing left as exercise to reader.

Comment: You should put the `+` inside the `()` so that you can get back the two matching results more easily. `+` works with anything, including `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to match a specific pattern such as "This" or "Test" you can simply do a case insensitive string compare.

From your question, I'm not sure that you necessarily need a regular expression here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick LINQpad:

```
var r = new Regex("(.*) is a (.*)");
var match = r.Match("This is a test");
match.Groups.OfType<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g=>g.Value).Dump();
```

That outputs:

```
IEnumerable<String> (2 items)
This 
test
```